# ReactJS, it won't rerender child component on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am implementing fitness tracker, and having trouble on rendering child component depends on the index.

Once I click on the button, Workout component should display object that is on the chosen index but it's not re-rendering. I have tried to add log, and in the log the value is changing but it is just not re-rendering. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

My main function is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Workout from "./Workout";
import sampleData from "./sampleData";

export default function App() {
  const [exerciseIndex, setExerciseIndex] = useState(0);
  const [renderWorkout, setRenderWorkout] = useState([
    sampleData[exerciseIndex]
  ]);

  const handleClick = currentIndex => {
    //console.log(currentIndex);
    setExerciseIndex(currentIndex);
    setRenderWorkout(sampleData[exerciseIndex]);
  };

  const navVal = sampleData.map((exercise, index) => {
    return (
      <button key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
        {exercise.date}
      </button>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Workouts</h1>
      <br />
      {navVal}
      <Workout initialValues={renderWorkout[exerciseIndex]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and sampleData look like below

```
const data = [
  {
    workout: [
      {
        exerciseId: 1,
        exerciseName: "BenchPress",
        sets: [
          {
            setId: 1,
            weight: 75,
            reps: 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseId: 2,
        exerciseName: "Deadlift",
        sets: [
          {
            setId: 2,
            weight: 135,
            reps: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseId: 3,
        exerciseName: "Squat",
        sets: [
          {
            setId: 3,
            weight: 135,
            reps: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    date: 1
  },

  {
    workout: [
      {
        exerciseId: 1,
        exerciseName: "Squat",
        sets: [
          {
            setId: 1,
            weight: 75,
            reps: 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseId: 2,
        exerciseName: "Good Morning",
        sets: [
          {
            setId: 2,
            weight: 135,
            reps: 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        exerciseId: 3,
        exerciseName: "Leg Raise",
        sets: [
          {
            setId: 3,
            weight: 135,
            reps: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    date: 22
  }
];

export default data;
```

Workout component

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import update from "react-addons-update";

/*const initialValues = {
  ...sampleData,
  newExerciseName: ""
};*/

export default function Workout(props) {
  let newData;
  function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "topTextChange":
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value
        };

      case "addSet":
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          [action.payload - 1]: {
            sets: {
              $push: [
                {
                  setId: state.workout[action.payload - 1].sets.length + 1,
                  weight: 0,
                  reps: 0
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };

      case "removeSet":
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          [action.payload - 1]: {
            sets: {
              $splice: [[state.workout[action.payload - 1].sets.length - 1, 1]]
            }
          }
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };

      case "addExercise":
        console.log(state);
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          $push: [
            {
              exerciseId: state.workout.length + 1,
              exerciseName: state.newExerciseName,
              sets: []
            }
          ]
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };
      case "deleteExercise":
        const position = state.workout.findIndex(
          exercise => exercise.exerciseId === action.payload
        );
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          $splice: [[position, 1]]
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, props.data);

  const addExercise = () => dispatch({ type: "addExercise" });
  const deleteExercise = id =>
    dispatch({ type: "deleteExercise", payload: id });

  const changeText = e =>
    dispatch({ type: "topTextChange", payload: e.target });

  const renderedExercise = state.workout.map((exercise, index) => {
    console.log(exercise);

    return <Exercise key={index} exercise={exercise} />;
  });

  function Set(props) {
    // ToDo: hook up below values to states
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Weight <input type="text" value={props.weight} />{" "}
        </label>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Reps <input type="text" value={props.rep} />{" "}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Exercise(props) {
    const renderedSet = props.exercise.sets.map((set, index) => (
      <Set key={index} weight={set.weight} rep={set.reps} />
    ));

    const addSet = id => dispatch({ type: "addSet", payload: id });
    const deleteSet = id => dispatch({ type: "removeSet", payload: id });

    return (
      <div>
        {props.exercise.exerciseName}
        <button onClick={() => deleteExercise(props.exercise.exerciseId)}>
          {" "}
          Remove Exercise{" "}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => addSet(props.exercise.exerciseId)}>
          {" "}
          Add Set{" "}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => deleteSet(props.exercise.exerciseId)}>
          Remove Set
        </button>
        {renderedSet}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="Workout">
      {renderedExercise}
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="newExerciseName"
        value={state.newExerciseName}
        placeholder="What exercise do you want to add?"
        onChange={e => changeText(e)}
      />{" "}
      <button onClick={() => addExercise()}>Add Exercise</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous. When you call `setRenderWorkout(sampleData[exerciseIndex]);` it will not use the new value for `exerciseIndex` but the old one.

Comment: Hi Jake, I think you have not called setState function to actually update the state of the component. What does the setExerciseIndex look like?

Comment: In this very special case, the fix seems to be pretty simple; there's no need to even have a separate `renderWorkout` state; just use `sampleData[exerciseIndex]` instead.

Comment: @ChrisG, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I tried to use sampleData[exerciseIndex] for initialValue of Workout component but it is still not re-rendering on the button..

Comment: @RobFyffe, thanks for your reply. I am using useState hook.

Comment: Rewrote it a bit, works fine now: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dubinsky-tkw6o

Comment: Thank you Chris G, I appreciate it. What is weird tho... I have almost identical code for it but mine don't work. I am wondering it's because my workout component not working properly. If you have chance, could you please have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/tracker-c57li ? meanwhile I will try to see if there is something I am missing....

Comment: you know what I realize it has something to do with child component not updating the state properly. I may not be passing updated values to update state in child component. I have also posted my child component implementation....

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was because I had state in the child component 'Workout', and I was not updating it as it was changed from parent component 'App'. I used forwardRef,useRef, and useImperativeHandle to update the state from parent component. Now it's working as expected. See below for updated implementation. For more information on those hooks, look official ReactJS guide or https://itnext.io/changing-children-state-from-another-component-with-react-hooks-5c982c042e8 is where I found my solution

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Workout from "./Workout";
import sampleData from "./sampleData";

export default function App() {
  const workoutRef = useRef(null);

  const navVal = sampleData.map((exercise, index) => {
    return (
      <button key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
        {exercise.date}
      </button>
    );
  });

  const handleClick = currentIndex => {
    workoutRef.current.updateExercise(sampleData[currentIndex]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Workouts</h1>
      <br />
      {navVal}
      <Workout ref={workoutRef} data={sampleData[0]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Workout.js

```
import React, { useReducer, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import update from "react-addons-update";

const Workout = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  let newData;
  function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "topTextChange":
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value
        };

      case "addSet":
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          [action.payload - 1]: {
            sets: {
              $push: [
                {
                  setId: state.workout[action.payload - 1].sets.length + 1,
                  weight: 0,
                  reps: 0
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };

      case "removeSet":
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          [action.payload - 1]: {
            sets: {
              $splice: [[state.workout[action.payload - 1].sets.length - 1, 1]]
            }
          }
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };

      case "addExercise":
        console.log(state);
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          $push: [
            {
              exerciseId: state.workout.length + 1,
              exerciseName: state.newExerciseName,
              sets: []
            }
          ]
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };
      case "deleteExercise":
        const position = state.workout.findIndex(
          exercise => exercise.exerciseId === action.payload
        );
        newData = update(state.workout, {
          $splice: [[position, 1]]
        });
        return {
          ...state,
          workout: newData
        };
      case "replaceExercise":
        return {
          ...action.payload
        };
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, props.data);

  const addExercise = () => dispatch({ type: "addExercise" });
  const deleteExercise = id =>
    dispatch({ type: "deleteExercise", payload: id });

  const changeText = e =>
    dispatch({ type: "topTextChange", payload: e.target });

  const renderedExercise = state.workout.map((exercise, index) => {
    return <Exercise key={index} exercise={exercise} />;
  });

  const updateExercise = data => {
    dispatch({ type: "replaceExercise", payload: data });
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      updateExercise: updateExercise
    };
  });

  function Set(props) {
    // ToDo: hook up below values to states
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Weight <input type="text" value={props.weight} />{" "}
        </label>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Reps <input type="text" value={props.rep} />{" "}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Exercise(props) {
    const renderedSet = props.exercise.sets.map((set, index) => (
      <Set key={index} weight={set.weight} rep={set.reps} />
    ));

    const addSet = id => dispatch({ type: "addSet", payload: id });
    const deleteSet = id => dispatch({ type: "removeSet", payload: id });

    return (
      <div>
        {props.exercise.exerciseName}
        <button onClick={() => deleteExercise(props.exercise.exerciseId)}>
          {" "}
          Remove Exercise{" "}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => addSet(props.exercise.exerciseId)}>
          {" "}
          Add Set{" "}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => deleteSet(props.exercise.exerciseId)}>
          Remove Set
        </button>
        {renderedSet}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="Workout">
      {renderedExercise}
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="newExerciseName"
        value={state.newExerciseName}
        placeholder="What exercise do you want to add?"
        onChange={e => changeText(e)}
      />{" "}
      <button onClick={() => addExercise()}>Add Exercise</button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Workout;
```